# What it means (myform)="function()" in angular

Tags: angular

Hello i have a code like this

```
<div class="add-item-container">
  <app-additemform (myform)="addItem($event)"></app-additemform>
```

I don't know what "()" is exactly do .

Also in my form component which is different component. I have a code like this

```
 @Output() myform : EventEmitter<BudgetItem> = new EventEmitter<BudgetItem>();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the doc ? https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#how-to-use-output

Comment: when in app-additemform you execute `this.myform.emit("hello word");` -well really you emit an object of type BudgetItem-, you execute the function `addItem` with the argument "hello word". Is like you write in the .html `<div (click)="doSomething($event)>..</div>`, when you click the function "doSomething" is executed. Angular allow us to create "custom events"